# Feature extraction and classification in digital image processing techniques

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on a project for the classification of lungs as cancerous or normal depending on the existence of nodules in CT images , such that if there exists a nodule  the MATLAB detects this input case as a cancerous case , otherwise MATLAB detect this case as a normal one. Currently i have successfully developed a technique that can extract any nodule ( if exists ) in the lungs and if there is no  nodule matlab will extract some noise ( bronchi ), which does not have any rounded shape like any nodule. Now can anyone please suggests sources for learning feature extraction using MATLAB and also sources for learning Artificial neural network ( theoretically and also using Matlab ) for classification ? I am looking forward to extract features such as geometrical features ( shape , area , perimeter ) and features such as contrast. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd start with these:

https://it.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/features.html#deep-learning
https://it.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/features.html#object-detection-and-recognition

there are lots of ready-to-be used tools that might be useful, i'd look at them before starting writing something new.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank for your recommendation , i will be thankful if you provide me with any good textbooks or papers .